# Why not abstract policies?

Tags: c++, boost, policy

When implementing policies, one needs to follow a specific interface. From what I understand the policies have to be able to replace each other. In modern c++ book, Ch 1.5 3 policies have the same interface "T* Create() {}". Why is there no need to abstract it. It would be important if there are number of interfaces that policies should have. from I understand abstract class gives a recipe for which interfaces should be in concrete classes (the policy classes). In the [Wikipedia example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design#Simple_example) "using" defines which interfaces the policy should have but it's not through an abstract class. Isn't the point of abstract class to make sure that derived classes have the required interfaces?

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference in that an interface using an abstract base class has virtual functions providing runtime polymorphism.

The policies are used to provide compile time polymorphism for the templates. The compiler will notice if your policy class has a `T* Create()` or not. If it doesn't, you will get a compile time error when trying to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I've never actually used policy-based design in practice and it's ages since I coded in C++, but here's my interpretation. As you've pointed out, the host class can enforce constraints on the policies used with it, either through interfaces, or through something like `using output_policy::Print;`, as the wiki example depicts.

An advantage (or difference) of the using method is that it's less proactively restrictive and less rigid, as policies have an implied contract which is represented directly by the code which uses them. In the using example, given the current state of the code, the output_policy implementation need only implement a method called Print which returns anything and takes whatever language_policy::Message() returns (in this case, all language_policies return a std::string). This is a little closer to duck typing.

One disadvantage is that the implied contract disappears once the code goes away. Another disadvantage is that policies have some level of dependency on each other. As a very contrived example, if one output_policy has a non-generic Print method which prints only strings, it cannot be used with a language_policy which prints only integers.

I don't see why you can't add policy interfaces if needed. One example is where the HelloWorld class might want to constrain the output_policy so that it prints strings and nothing else. You could achieve this by coding something like the below - note that you'd have to use SFINAE to enforce that `output_policy<std::string>` actually implements `OutputPolicyInterface<std::string>`.

```
template<typename message_type>
class OutputPolicyInterface
{
    virtual void Print( message_type message ) = 0;
};


template <template<class> class output_policy, typename language_policy>
class HelloWorld : public output_policy<std::string>, public language_policy
{

public:
    void Run()
    {
        Print( Message() );
        //Print(2);  won't work anymore
    }
};
```